# Error (index):74 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cmd' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cmd

Hi I'm trying to create an html script tag within a react component and incorporate google ads but getting this

> error (index):74 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cmd' of
>   undefined

.

I'm very new to react so this might be a simple fix but not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here is a snapshot of my component GoogleAdUnit code. 
[GoogleAdUnit Component Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecZYl.png)

If you need anymore information please let me know and I can provide it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: please include code snippets of what you have done so far. That will help others understand why you got the error

Answer (score 0):

You are using "googletag" even though you never defined it before, thus it is undefined and you can't use googletag.cmd.